# sqlite, how to get the last n records whitout ORDER BY

Tags: sqlite

I need to take the last 7 values of a column I was thinking of using 'LIMIT' but I don't know if it also works in reverse. Take an example, I have these values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10; I need to get 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, considering the fact that in the future other records will be added after 10. Is there a solution with 'LIMIT' or are there other solutions? I can't use ORDER BY 'couse the values i need get are the last 7 days of values and sqlite don't have date type and I don't registered date as milliseconds but i do in date format dd-mm-yyyy so use 'ORDER BY date' don't works. Thanks

Comment: Change the format of the dates to: `yyyy-mm-dd` and then you can order by date.

Comment: @forpas this is a good hack and idea. I take it into consideration. Thanks

Comment: Tables are unordered so there is not such thing as *last 7 values* without some kind of sorting.

Comment: It's not a hack. Using one of the formats supported by [sqlite date and time functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) is the best way to handle dates in sqlite; they can be sorted, work with those functions, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the format of the dates to `YYYY-MM-DD` then it is as simple as this:

```
SELECT columnname 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 7
```

As it is now the date format the only thing that you can do is construct the proper format in the `ORDER BY` clause with [`SUBSTR()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

```
SELECT columnname 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY SUBSTR(date, 7) || SUBSTR(date, 4, 2) || SUBSTR(date, 1, 2) DESC
LIMIT 7
```

This expression:

```
SUBSTR(date, 7) || SUBSTR(date, 4, 2) || SUBSTR(date, 1, 2)
```

transforms a date like `05-01-2020` to `20200105` so it is comparable and can be used to sort the rows.